# Install Commerce 2.x project template windows using composer and got HTTP 500 error

Tags: commerce

I want to install Drupal Commerce 2.x in Drupal 8.x in Windows. I followed as in  Commerce 2.x project template in Github. I installed composer and from my cmd window, I ran command: composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore1 --stability dev --no-interaction

All was going fine. It loaded many components like phpunit 4.8.27. Then it displayed messages like commerceguys/addressing suggests installing sysfony/intl ... and like these. Then Writing lock file ,  Generating autoload file, Downloading file:100%, Downloading file:100%,

Then I got Downloading file:Failed

Composer/Downloader/TransportException
The "http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/plain/.eslintignore?h-8.2.0-rc1: file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error)

I also searched if it had created some folder somerwhere in my C:\xampp\htdocs or somewhere, I could not get anywhere. Please help me install it completely and access drupal from browser. 
I have attached screenshot. The errors are seen in lower section:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Retry ! It solves download issues. 
Then find project location in C:\Users\current_user\project_name
Copy inside htdocs and browse localhost\project_name\web and continue installation.